# Shape not drawing using mouse events outside of paintGL function - QT OpenGL C++

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have this function that should draw a rect based on where the user clicks and drags however nothing is drawn. I have tried using the `updateGL()` function however that returns an error. I've also tried to use QPainter but I was not sure how to work it with the code below. I've also tried using `makeCurrent()` and `doneCurrent()` but that makes the program "unexpectedly finish".

#### shape drawing functions:

```
void drawingArea::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    paintGL();
}

void drawingArea::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    Shape newShape;
    int x = event->x(),y = event->y();
    shapes.push_back(newShape);
    Point newPoint(x,y);
    shapes[0].addPoint(newPoint);
}

void drawingArea::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QVector<int> startPoint = shapes[0].points[0].getPoint();
    int vertices[]
    {
        event->x(),event->y(),0,
        event->x(),startPoint[1],0,
        event->x(),event->y(),0,
        startPoint[0],event->y(),0
    };
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3,GL_INT,0,vertices);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS,0,4);
    QPainter painter(this);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    update();

}
```

Also I do have this intializer function and maybe that the reason but when I try to run `context->makeCurrent()` it throws an error so I've commented it out but I'll drop the function incase it is that

```
drawingArea::drawingArea(QWidget *parent) : QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{
    //initializeGL();
    //paintGL();
    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CompatibilityProfile);
    format.setVersion(2,1);
    setFormat(format);

    context = new QOpenGLContext;
    context->setFormat(format);
    context->create();
    //context->makeCurrent(this->);
    openGLFunctions = context->functions();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute an OpenGL instruction, an valid and current [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) is needed. [`QOpenGLWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html) provides such an OpenGL context, when the event callback methods `initializeGL()`, `paintGL()` and `resizeGL()` a re executed.

If you want to use en OpenGL instruction in a mouse event callback, then you have to make the OpenGL context current by [`makeCurrent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#makeCurrent) and releases it by [`doneCurrent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#doneCurrent):

For instance:

```cpp
void drawingArea::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    makeCurrent()

    // [...]

    doneCurrent()
}
```

Side note, never call the `paintGL` callback function directly. Use [`update()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update) to schedules a paint even.

Comment: I've tried this already and the program crashes and i get 'The program has unexpectedly finished. The process was ended forcefully.

Comment: @TavianT Sorry, I can just explain what you have to do, but I can't debug your code.